# Git, revert or reset to a certain commit

Tags: git

I have several a,b,c,d,e made and published. No I noticed errors and want to reset my entire project to commit b. Since it is published I read that I should not use reset to not re-write history. Revert, on the other hand, does only revert individual commits.

Is there way to revert all commits since commit b t once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `reset --hard` to rewrite history; I do it plenty. You just need to be *absolutely sure* that there are no consequences to losing your work.

Answer (score 5):

You can revert a range of commit by `git revert <from-commit>..<to-commit>`.

```
$ git revert -n c..HEAD
```

This reverts the changes done by commits from the `c` (included) to `HEAD` (included), but do not create any commit with the reverted changes. The revert only modifies the working tree and the index.

Then you need to commit :

```
$ git commit -m 'Revert commit from c to HEAD'
```

[See More](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert#git-revert-codegitrevert-nmaster5master2code)